# How To Properly Handle A 404 IDHTTP Error

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe4

I am having trouble understanding how to trap a http exception with idHTTP.  Should idHTTP errors be handled in a IDHTTP event or like the code shown below?

```
try
  iIdHTTP.Get(iURL,iComponentStream[0]);
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
  begin
    MessageBox(0, PChar(ActiveImage_IdHTTP[0].ResponseText), 'HTTP Error', MB_ICONWARNING or MB_OK);
    exit;
  end;
end;
```

Either I must be doing something totally incorrect or something is strange is occurring.  When I call this, and a 404 exception occurs and the exception dialog ok button is selected and the dialog closes, but the code in the exception block is not called and the messagebox never appears.  What am I doing incorrectly?

When an exception occurs are there error codes that can be used to this a little better like show a 404 error in a messagebox?  Where can I find a list of TIDHTTP error codes?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your `except` block *will* run, unless you disabled exception handling, or `TIdHTTP` is raising something other than `EIdHTTPProtocolException`. Yes, you should be using a `try/except` to handle HTTP errors, unless you enable the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property. As for the error codes, they are defined in the HTTP specification. Look at [RFC 2616 Section 10](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10).

Comment: BTW, you should be displaying `E.Message` and/or `E.ErrorMessage` instead of `ActiveImage_IdHTTP[0].ResponseText` in the `MessageBox()`.

Comment: Thanks Remy... All my errors are 404 errors  How do you trap that... on E: EID404Exception? or does EIdHTTPProtocolException handle everything?  Nothing specific can be used for 404?

Comment: `EIdHTTPProtocolException` handles all HTTP errors. If you want to differentiate between error codes, you can use the exception's `ErrorCode` property.